# ASP.NET Core Docker Container App not accessible

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, https

I run an ASP.NET Core service in a Docker container on MacOS.
Visual Studio for Mac v18.1.2 (build 2)
.NET Core SDK: 2.2.300

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
WORKDIR /
COPY src/Services/Service.API/Service.API.csproj src/Services/Service.API/
RUN dotnet restore src/Services/Service.API/Service.API.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Services/Service.API
RUN dotnet build Service.API.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish Service.API.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Service.API.dll"]
```

Here is how the docker-compose file for the service looks like:

```
service.api:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: src/Services/Service.API/Dockerfile
  environment:
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80;https://+:443
    - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5254 
    - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=crypticpassword
    - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
  ports:
    - "5204:80"
    - "5254:443"
  volumes:
    - ${HOME}/.aspnet/https:/https/
```

The ports of the running Docker container looks good too:

> 0.0.0.0:5204->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5254->443/tcp

But when I try to call https://localhost:5254 it says site cannot be reached.

Also in the output I see following warning:

> warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
>         Unable to bind to https://localhost:5001 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel:Warning: Unable to bind to
>   https://localhost:5001 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign
>   requested address'. Hosting environment: Development Content root
>   path: /app Now listening on: https://localhost:5001

Why doesn't it take the urls set by the ASPNETCORE_URLS enivronment variable?

What else could I do for troubleshooting to find the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in Visual Studio for Mac v18.1.2 (docker-compose up works)

Comment: On windows 10 using docker desktop and linux containers it's not accessible too...

Answer (score 6):

I had your problem a while ago, this is how I fixed it. You need to specify `--server.urls` as a running argument like below:

```
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Service.API.dll", "--server.urls", "http://+:80;https://+:443"]
```

And where that `5000` and `5001` come from?

[Kestrel Endpoint configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#endpoint-configuration)

> By default, ASP.NET Core binds to:
>
> http://localhost:5000
>
> https://localhost:5001 (when a local development
>   certificate is present)

**Update 1:**

According to your docker-compose configuration, you have set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `Development`. I think you should change it to `Production` because when you enable `Development` the `ASP.NET Core` will read settings from `launchSettings.json`.

The development environment can enable features that shouldn't be exposed in production. For example, the ASP.NET Core templates enable the Developer Exception Page in the development environment.

> The environment for local machine development can be set in the
>   Properties\launchSettings.json file of the project. Environment values
>   set in launchSettings.json override values set in the system
>   environment.

As far as I remember the default ports for `Kestrel` are `80` and `443` in every default `launchSettings.json`.

If you need to run your project in `development` mode on Docker you should change configuration inside `launchSettings.json` but I think it's not recommended and it's better to change the mode to `Production`.

```
service.api:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: src/Services/Service.API/Dockerfile
  environment:
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
    - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80;https://+:443
    - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5254 
    - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=crypticpassword
    - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
  ports:
    - "5204:80"
    - "5254:443"
  volumes:
    - ${HOME}/.aspnet/https:/https/
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help. Same problem. Also according to your link you can use the ASPNETCORE_URLS environment variable, what I do, but it seems to just ignore it and use the default bindings.

Comment: @Palmi I see, I updated the answer please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

First, check if your container is up and running with:

`docker ps`

If it is running, Kestrel inside the container may not be started. You may need to check your entrypoint, Linux in the container is case sensitive. In this case, try to run your app manually. First, get into the container by:

`docker exec -it your_container /bin/bash`

`cd /app`

`dotnet yourprojectfile.dll`

and then navigate:

https://localhost:5254

Comment: container is up and running. Regarding the entrypoint, I added the Dockerfile in my question

Comment: Did you check the Kestrel? Is it running too?

Comment: How do I check it in the container?

Comment: Just do `docker exec -it your_container /bin/bash`

Comment: Or `docker logs your_container` if you want to follow the logs use: `docker logs -f your_container` syntax

Comment: dotnet Service.API.dll in the container returns: Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409

Answer (score 2):

Basically, in the asp.net core code, it only listens to localhost which is in Container, but not your local pc. You can solve the issue by updating your setting to listen "http://*:5000" instead of "http://localhost:5000".

Here is a detailed explaination of the cause and solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65953771/8918445

Answer (score 0):

For your current `docker-compose.yml`, you are referring the existing image `service.api:${TAG:-latest}` directly instead of using the generated image from the dockerfile.

Remove this line `image: service.api:${TAG:-latest}`

```
version: '3'
services:
  service.api:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: src/Services/Service.API/Dockerfile
  environment:
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80;https://+:443
    - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5254 
    - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=crypticpassword
    - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
  ports:
    - "5204:80"
    - "5254:443"
  volumes:
    - ${HOME}/.aspnet/https:/https/
```

Comment: I removed it in my question. I just tried to merge the the docker-compose.yml and docker-compose.override.yml to simplify it for the question...

Comment: @Palmi What do you mean by merge docker-compose.yam and docker-compose.override.yml? Run `docker container -ls -a` to see whether there is any container with image name `service.api`, remove them and run `docker-compose up` again. Not sure whether you configured anywhere, try to use this dockerfile and docker-compose with a new default .net core project.

Answer (score 0):

in my case when used *(star sign) instead of localhost then everything is ok(urls=http://*:5000 instead of urls=http://localhost:5000).

use bellow code in Dockerfile(create file with name "Dockerfile" in parent directory of your project publish directory)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
WORKDIR /App
COPY ./your project publish folder/ .
ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myproject.dll","urls=http://*:5000"]
```

then build and generate docker image file:

```
sudo docker build -t mydockerimage:0.3 .
```

then run project as docker container:

```
docker run -it  -td -p 5000:5000 mydockerimage:0.3
```

then you can test website by curl command:

```
curl localhost:5000
```

you can check your website log with this command:

```
docker container logs "your containr ids"
```